# Spain jobs, relocation packages?

Tags: spain, relocation

Offered a job in Spain. The relocation package is one way air fare + 2-week hotel for house hunting. Aka no funding to ship goods across Atlantic from Us.

Is this pretty typical for Spanish employers or is full relocation something that should be expected?

Comment: I’d imagine what is ‘typical’ depends on eg the industry/employer/job/location. A highly skilled role with a major corporation would be likely to offer a more comprehensive package IMHO

Comment: I have more often seen the opposite: money for freight shipping, airfares is on you (and even more often nothing at all).